# Check today if in dates array

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to check if today  ( at 0:00 ) is in a dates array, like so:

```js
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var holidays = [
  new Date(2017, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0).getTime(), // Today
  new Date(2017, 5, 22, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 23, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 24, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 25, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
];
if ($.inArray(today, holidays) > -1) {
  alert('Closed');
} else {
  alert('Open');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But as you can see, it's not finding today ( 21th of june ),

Any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: Why are you using a massive library for *inArray* when there is the built-in *indexOf*? `alert( holidays.indexOf(+today) == -1? 'Open':'Closed')`.

Comment: Because i'm working on a project that already makes use of it. So it's not only for that :)

Comment: Even so, I'd expect *indexOf* to be very much more efficient than a function that loops over all the elements in the array, even if it gets a match on the first one.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, but it's irrelevant for the question.. :)

Comment: That's why it's a comment. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were comparing a date object with time :

```js
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var holidays = [
  new Date(2017, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0).getTime(), // Today
  new Date(2017, 5, 22, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 23, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 24, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 25, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
];
if ($.inArray(today.getTime(), holidays) > -1) {
  alert('Closed');
} else {
  alert('Opened');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your $.inArray call, change "today" to "today.getTime()"

Answer (score 0):

`today` and `today.getTime()` are different.

```js
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
today=today.getTime();
var holidays = [
  new Date(2017, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0).getTime(), // Today
  new Date(2017, 5, 22, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 23, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 24, 0, 0, 0).getTime(),
  new Date(2017, 5, 25, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
];
if ($.inArray(today, holidays) > -1) {
  alert('Closed');
} else {
  alert('Opened');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```